# Derivative of the test function.

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

For any real number $T$, choose special test function, $f(t)=-1$ when $t\in[0,T]$,  $f(t)=0$ when $t\not\in[0,T]$. My book say $f'(t)=\delta(t-T)-\delta(t)$ but I don't know why. In my opinion, it might be $0$ since it is constant function for each interval. How can I calculate it?

**EDIT:** I roughly feel it since definition of derivative says its slopes  approaches to $-\infty$ when $0$ and $T$(may be $\infty$ when $T$, intuitively). But I can't prove and accept clearly.

Comment: Your book should be dealing with distributions.

Comment: That's not a valid test function. But it's a function that defines a distribution.

Comment: Yes this book is dealing with distribution. Although it is not a smooth function, I wrote 'the test function' since this book say 'Choose the following special test function $f(t)$'.

Comment: Imagine a smooth version of your box distribution, that has very sudden changes at the boundaries. Then draw what the derivative looks like. It should approximate the 2 delta functions. That should give an intuitive understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a distribution $u$ the derivative of it is defined by
$$
\langle u', \varphi \rangle = - \langle u, \varphi' \rangle
$$
for all test functions $\varphi.$

Therefore, take a test function $\varphi$ and rewrite
$$
- \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, \varphi'(t) \, dt
$$
so that there are only $\varphi$, no $\varphi'.$ Useful is to insert the definition of $f$ and then integrate by parts.

Give it a try!